# GORM executeUpdate query

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

How to write [GORM executeUpdate](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeUpdate.html) query for the following SQL Query

```
UPDATE student_marks sm SET
    sm.totalMarks = sm.theoryMarks + sm.homeAssignmentMarks
WHERE
    sm.homeAssignmentMarks IS NOT NULL
        AND sm.theoryMarks IS NOT NULL
            AND sm.theoryMarks = sm.totalMarks
                AND sm.examHeldIn = 6;
```

Here theoryMarks and homeAssignmentMarks are String.

Answer (score 0):

```
def map = [:]
map.examHeldInt = 6

StudentMarks.executeUpdate("""
    UPDATE StudentMarks sm SET
        sm.totalMarks = CAST(sm.theoryMarks AS int) + CAST(sm.homeAssignmentMarks AS int)
    WHERE
        sm.homeAssignmentMarks IS NOT NULL
            AND sm.theoryMarks IS NOT NULL
                AND sm.theoryMarks = sm.totalMarks
                    AND sm.examHeldIn = :examHeldIn""", map)
```

Something like above  you need to case the strings as int to be able to add them  look up cast and concat